# Posting JSON request and reading EventStreams in Angular11

Tags: javascript, angular, web, observer-pattern, event-stream

Tried following the article below to read eventstreams. Instead of using `formData` like it is done in the article, I'm using Json to post. It works smoothly with a 200 response. Even tells that some kb of data was sent over the wire, but the eventstream tab shows nothing. The same curl works on my terminal.

https://medium.com/swlh/how-do-server-sent-events-sse-or-eventsource-work-in-angular-e9e27b6a3295

[image: Network call of the stream]

[image: EventStream tab in the network call]

Comment: did you correctly subscribe to it in js, also did you put correct stream headers on BE side and events are of correct format?

Comment: @Andrei I tried doing it using fetch, similar response, but using its curl seems to work fine on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the article

```
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      const eventSource = this.sseService.getEventSourceWithPost(url, data);
      // Launch query
      eventSource.stream();
      // on answer from message listener 
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(event.progress);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
      };
    });
```

Changing this part to

```
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      const eventSource = this.sseService.getEventSourceWithPost(url, data);
      // Launch query
      eventSource.stream();
      // on answer from message listener 
      eventSource.addEventListener('EVENT_NAME_FROM_STREAM', (event) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(event.data);
        });
      };
    });
```

Got the data to show up. But in the network tab I still don't see the events.